# JavaScript Image Swap Errors

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an Image Swap with Javascript. Can anyone point me in the direction of where my coding error is in JavaScript? Am I using the getElementByID incorrectly? Any help or direction is much appreciated!

```
<title>Photo Gallery</title>
</head>
    <header>
        <h1>Gallery</h1>
        <div>
            <img alt="images" src="Skelton_ImageSwap/images/Lilly.jpg" 
            style="height: 350px; width: 350px" id="Lilly">
        </div>
    </header>
    <body>
    <img src="Skelton_ImageSwap/images/Lilly.jpg" alt ="images" id ='Lilly' onclick.changeImage()>
    <img src ="Skelton_ImageSwap/images/Lotus.jpg" alt = "images" id='Lotus' onclick.changeImage()>
    <img src="Skelton_ImageSwap/images/Roses.jpg" alt="images" id='Roses'onclick.changeImage()>
    <img src="Skelton_ImageSwap/images/Tulip.jpg" alt="images" id='Tulip'onclick.changeImage()>
    </body>

            <script>
                function changePicture()
                {
                     if (image.getElementByID.onclick.changePicture == "Lilly")
                {
                    image.src = "Skelton_ImageSwap/image/Lilly.jpg";
                }
                if (image.getElementByID.onclick.changePicture == "Orchid")
                {
                    image.src = "Skelton_ImageSwap/image/Orchid.jpg";
                }
                if (image.getElementByID.onclick.image == "Roses")
                {
                    image.src = "Skelton_ImageSwap/image/Roses.jpg";
                }
                else
                {
                     image.src = "Skelton_ImageSwap/image/Tulip.jpg";
                }
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: With the image swap I am trying to have it where when the thumbnail picture is clicked on it will take place of <div> image. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: There's a whole range of issues with your code, but I think [the documentation for `getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#Example) should clear up how that function and the HTML `onclick` attribute are supposed to be used. Once you've done that, you have a logic issue in that your `else` block runs in 3 out of 4 cases. Also your `image` variable is never declared and you use `changePicture` vs `changeImage` as if they were synonymous.

Comment: I also suggest looking up how to open the web developer console for your browser, as that should aid you greatly in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

On your img tags the onclick function is not wrote correctly should look like

```
onClick="changeImage()"
```

Also "changeImage" is not a function you wrote a function called "changePicture" so it should really look like

```
onClick="changePicture()"
```

Now in your changePicture function there are a few issues specifically the getElementById function is not being used correctly also you got the name wrong on it you capitalized the 'D' at the end which shouldn't be, I would recommend changing the id on your header tag img from 'Lilly' to 'preview' since element id's need to be unique and you've already used 'Lilly' as an id than replace your script tag with this

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("Lilly").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("preview").src = "Skelton_ImageSwap/image/Lilly.jpg"
    });
    document.getElementById("Lotus").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("preview").src = "Skelton_ImageSwap/image/Lotus.jpg"
    });
    document.getElementById("Roses").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("preview").src = "Skelton_ImageSwap/image/Roses.jpg"
    });
    document.getElementById("Tulip").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("preview").src = "Skelton_ImageSwap/image/Tulip.jpg"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Also make sure the src you're setting them as in the script tag is the correct src for your project I see you using "Skelton_ImageSwap/images/" in your html but in the script you're setting them as "Skelton_ImageSwap/image/" do you have both an image and images directory in your project

Comment: Thank you for your help! I can definitely see where I had taken a wrong turn now. I think I was trying to make it much more complicated than it needed to be.

Comment: No problem if you need a different solution let me know